# Windows phone 8 app is not running on device

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

Is it mandatory to switch on the pc or system to run windows phone 8 application on device, if I turned off the system or shut down my pc, the Windows 8 app is not running, I have added WCF service in Windows 8 app.
Please help me!
Thanks!!

Here is my Java web serviceurl : "xxx//xxx/xxx?wsdl.

I have added service reference of that url, named ServiceReference1.
See my code below

```
ServiceReference1.CommonWsEndPointClient client = new ServiceReference1.CommonWsEndPointClient();
client.m98123Async();
client.m98123Completed += client_m98123Completed;

void client_m98123Completed(object sender, m98123CompletedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: No, normally it is not. Is your WCF service running on your PC? If so, it could be that your app crashes and throws an exception because your service is not available.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847085/windows-8-phone-application-issue

Comment: @Horizon_Net I have created web application and inside that project I have created WCf service. So is there any solution. Thnx for your quick reply!

Comment: From your other post I see that your service is running on a local IIS. How should your app reach your service? Of course, without a connection to your PC your app will crash if you don't have proper exception handling in place.

Comment: @Horizon_Net thank you so much man!I have one question, is there any way to add wsdl service directly in windows 8 app?

Comment: @Horizon_Net the web service is created in java and its url is like "http://xxx/xx?wsdl", if I add this url directly using service reference then in void completed() method, e.Result is not appearing, that is why I have created wcf service.

Comment: Can you update your post with the appropriate code snippet? Is the completed method your callback?

Comment: @Horizon_Net see my updated code, in my completed method, e.Result is not getting